# how create cvs file from image folders?

Tags: python, image

I have two image folders for skin cancer benign and malignant, I want to get the CSV file contains the first column is a path of the image and the second column is a label of the image in python language. how I can do that?

paths of dataset
'../input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/train/benign'

'../input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/train/malignant'

Comment: Could you be more specific on your need? What is "the label of the image"?
I assume that os.walk is a good starting point for such script

Comment: What is the extension on the image files? i.e. .png .jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `glob` module:

```py
benign = glob.glob('{path to benign folder}/*.png')
malignant = glob.glob('{path to malignant folder}/*.png')
```

the * here just means take the file path for **all** .png files in this folder. of course change .png to whatever image format you are using.

Then it's just a matter of writing the data

```py
import glob

benign = glob.glob('../input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/train/benign/*.png')
malignant = glob.glob('../input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/train/malignant/*.png')

CSV_FILE_NAME = 'my_file.csv'
with open(CSV_FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
    for path in benign:
        f.write(path)     # write the path in the first column
        f.write(',')      # separate first and second item by a comma
        f.write('benign') # write the label in the second column
        f.write('\n')     # start a new line
    
    for path in malignant:
        f.write(path)
        f.write(',')
        f.write('malignant')
        f.write('\n')
```

You can definitely write this more succinctly, but this is a bit more readable